# IValueConverter for collection

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, combobox, ivalueconverter

I have ComboBoxes than bind to collections of type int or double in my Silverlight application. These collections hold the possible valid values that can be selected by the user. I need to also have an "Auto" option in the ComboBox. In my code, I am representing "Auto" as -1. So, I am trying to find a way that I can take a collection of ints (with the possibility of the collection containing -1) and bind a ComboBox to it, with an IValueConverter making the -1 show up as "Auto". I have tried setting the Converter in the Binding on ItemsSource, but am having trouble creating a new collection with the formatted options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to try one more search before posting this question and finally came across my answer. The key in this situation is to **not** use the IValueConverter as the Converter for the ItemsSource binding, but rather to set up an ItemTemplate (I use it in a style):

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="AutoComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource autoConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The autoConverter is just a simple implementation of IValueConverter that checks if the value is -1, and if so it returns "Auto". ConvertBack does vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Below  is the example that might help you....

**Binding converter to Control:-**

---

<
sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clientReturnStatus" Binding="{Binding atclientreturns,
Converter={StaticResource ReturnStatusConverter}, ConverterParameter=ReturnStatus ,Mode=TwoWay}"
Header="Return Status"  Width="110"/>

---

**Convert Metho:-**

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)

```
    {
        string Text = "";            

        if (value != null)
        {                
            if(value == -1)
            {
                  Text = "Auto";
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        return Text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my issue. I need a ComboBox. I actually figured out the issue and have already posted the solution, I just can't mark it as the answer until tomorrow...